# Unable to change the visibility of HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the visisbility of a row of elements.
I am supposed to display the elements only if the user selects the button.

HTML code :

```
  <tr style="display:none">
      <td><input type="submit" value ="Home" onclick="" id="home"/></td>
      <td><input name="home_phone" id="home_phone" type="text" value="Phone" ></td>
  </tr>
```

JS code :

```
 document.getElementById("home").style.display = '';
 document.getElementById("home_phone").style.display = '';
```

I am trying to achive this using HTML and JS .

Comment: The Html code is  <tr style="display:none">
                        <td><input type="submit" value ="Home" onclick="" id="home"/></td>
                        <td><input name="home_phone" id="home_phone" type="text" value="Phone" ></td>
                     </tr>

Comment: I suggest you use jquery, its a big help.

Answer (score 4):

You JavaScript code is correct.

The problem is that you are setting the display value for an element that is nested within a hidden element.  You have to change the style of the `<tr>` because it is the hidden element.

HTML code:

```
<a href="javascript:toggleRow('home_row');">toggle home row visibility</a>

<table>
   <tr id="home_row">
      <td><input type="submit" value ="Home" onclick="" id="home"/></td>
      <td><input name="home_phone" id="home_phone" type="text" value="Phone" ></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

JS Code:

```
function toggleRow(rowId){
    var rowElement = document.getElementById(rowId);
    rowElement.style.display = rowElement.style.display.toLowerCase() == 'hidden'
                               ? 'table-row'
                               : 'hidden';
}
```

Comment: when i try the following approach , i get the following error .